# How to read in the specific text of PowerPoint slides in Python

Tags: python

This script is being created to help me with my homework for class. All we do is copy down slides from online and I am getting sick of wasting time doing it every week. We copy down vocab words every week from PowerPoint slides.

Each vocabulary word I am searching for is **BOLD** and has a definition after it that usually ends with a '.', and the goal is to get the VOCAB words and DEFINITION in a list or dictionary.

1. The script should start appending to the list after it hits a **BOLD FACE** word and stop when it hits a '.', all while continually doing this until there are no more words to read in.

What way should I be doing this with my for loops? How would I get this to be able to work?

I have tried messing with the loops and I have gotten some pretty strange results, such as multiple words over and over, extra periods, etc-...

My script is able to read all the text in from the PowerPoint file at this point, but I only want to read in certain texts.

```
from pptx import Presentation

for slide in prs.slides:
    for shape in slide.shapes:
        if not shape.has_text_frame:
            continue
        for paragraph in shape.text_frame.paragraphs:
            for run in paragraph.runs:
                if run.font.bold == True:
                     text_vocab.append(run.text)
                elif run != '.':
                         text_defin.append(run.text)
```

Link to the slides: http://www.filedropper.com/current

Comment: Probably `run != '.'` should be `run.endswith('.')`? Since you want to append to `text_defin` the runs which end with a `.`?

Comment: Yeah I tried that but it is not working.

Comment: Can you show how it's not working? It's easier to help if you can be specific about the problem.

Comment: @dsprencer Yeah sorry.. I am newer. The VOCAB words are being read in, I have used your method but I am not getting the desired result. I am trying to basically filter through all the UN-WANTED words in the powerpoint. I am getting things like "CHAPTER 1: HARDWARE" or "MCGRAW HILL" in the text_defin list. I would like to be able to get a section of words such as "The heart of the computer is the . " and at the blank spot of that string should of been the VOCAB word but that word is stored in text_vocab. I may be going at this problem all wrong and should get all the text first, then parse.

Comment: @dspencer I have tried going at it by finding some sort of algorithm based on the point size of the font used. I have noticed that the font size of vocab words and defintions are usually between 22 and 28 in size, I am currently messing around with that. Not having luck.

Comment: @dspencer here is the error I am getting with the font size alogrithm I am trying to do....     elif Pt(word[0]) >= Pt(22) and Pt(word[0]) <= Pt(28):
TypeError: '_Run' object is not subscriptable

Comment: Really, to be able to reproduce this, we would need an example slide. Can you use something like [File Dropper](https://www.filedropper.com/) to share one slide?

Comment: @dspencer yeah I will attempt to do that and let you know when it is finished.

Comment: @dspencer http://www.filedropper.com/current